# Magento 2: Resize the Image post

Tags: magento2, blog

How to Resize the Image post in **Magefan Blog** extension in Magento 2?

I have to tried with below solution but it's not worked for me.

- https://magefan.com/blog/resize-blog-post-images-programmatically
- [Magefan blog - images not showing after update](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187891/magefan-blog-images-not-showing-after-update)

Please Help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you have tried the above and not worked the only reason i can see is you have not regenerated your images as the images that were originally in place are no longer relevant so go to your command line and run the following "php bin/magento catalog:image:resize" minus quotes

Comment: @DavaGordon Gordon : Will this command work for my Blog image too?

Comment: If they have been implimented within the theme will post answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below solution is worked for me.

https://magefan.com/blog/resize-blog-post-images-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

If you have implimented the recommendation by the offical developer and it hasnt worked there are steps you can take which could help rectify the issue further.

Open app/design/frontend///etc/view.xml

Inside the

```
<images module="Magento_Catalog">
```

Add an additional deliration for an image size option

Official documentation regarding images can be found https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html but for refernece the 3 different types are

- thumbnail
- small_image
- image

  ```
      <image id="blog_post_image" type="small_image">
          <width>Your Width</width>
          <height>Your Height</height>
      </image>
  ```

Once you have added the above to your view.xml and please make sure you backup before doing any file edits.

Run the following command to regenerate your images, this will create a new cache based version of you images

```
php bin/magento catalog:image:resize
```

Comment: But i am not asking for the product images, but i asked for the Blog image.

Comment: Yeah all images within magento are cached and after reviewing the blog helper i can see that it uses the same method of getting images so on regeneration it should create all images within magento not just product images. also if you have tried https://magefan.com/blog/resize-blog-post-images-programmatically then should work i just did this on a local VM and worked as expected

Comment: Yup, it's now worked.i think it's a caching issue.

Comment: Glad to hear any other issues dont hesitate to message